# Access - Can Conditional Formatting be applied to text fields that Begin With...?

Tags: ms-access, report, conditional-formatting

I have an Access 2013 report based on a crosstab query which populates with training topics selected by the user as the column headings, and the employees names listed as the row headings with training dates (value field) under the appropriate column headings.  In order to identify training soon to expire, I created a calculated field for the training date that includes a prefix of 60, 30, 0 or just the date.  So the training date is now a text field that may look like    60  08/25/2016   or   0  05/10/2016, etc.  I would like to set conditional formatting to look for those prefixes, such as Begins With "60  " or "30  " or "0  ", or be able to use a wildcard.  I have tried Greater Than, but that does not work.  I have checked on the Microsoft Access Communities but cannot find anything about this.  I would sincerely appreciate any insight into this challenge!

Answer (score 1):

Use format rules of type `Expression`, with an expression like

```
Left([yourDateField], 3) = "60 "
```

or

```
Left([yourDateField], 2) = "0 "
```